# Force Suppress in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, suppress

How can I suppress a Details Section with a formula?

In my reports it may happen that a details section is empty. The only problem is, that CR wants to show the details section at least once because there are labels and some graphics in the Section...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you right click on the Details section  while in Design view you can choose Section Expert and then specify a formula which, if true, will suppress the Details section. (You don't say which Crystal Reports version you have, these instructions are for v10.)

You could use this formula for example:

```
count({detail_field},{group_field}) = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

like paulmorris said...go to the section expert and bring up the suppress formula for the details section. Enter a boolean expression that is true when you want to suppress, such as...

isnull({someFieldThatIndicatesTheDetailsWillBeEmpty})